# Mac OS Mojave can't open terminal from Cyberduck because that Not authorized to send Apple events to Terminal

Tags: macos-mojave, cyberduck

[image]

Mac OS Mojave can't open terminal from Cyberduck  because that Not authorized to send Apple events to Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked in [#10475](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/10475) and is fixed in the current snapshot build.